# Why syncing data do not work?

Tags: vue.js

I have Vue component, with [calendar component](https://github.com/weifeiyue/vue-datepicker) declared inside it:

```
var userContent = Vue.extend({
      props: ['startdate'],
      template: `
        <div>
            {{startdate}}
            <div class="calendar">                                       
              <mz-datepicker en format="yyyy-MM-dd" :startdate.sync="startdate"></mz-datepicker>
             </div>
        </div>`,

        data: function ()  
        {
          return 
          {
            startdate: '2011-11-11'
          }
        }
```

But when I am selecting new date in calendar the value of `{{startdate}}` do not changing and print original date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant `new Date('2011-11-11').getTime()`

As it says in the docs: https://github.com/weifeiyue/vue-datepicker/blob/master/demo.html

Comment: I am getting very strange result http://img.ctrlv.in/img/16/08/17/57b435a4c5a93.png

Comment: That's a unix-timestamp, it's the number of seconds since 1/1/1970 https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F

Comment: how can I convert (put in variable) in normal format YYYY-MM-DD ?

Comment: You can use moment.js `moment(1393939988839).format('YY-MM-DD')` http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Why if I am simply writing: `startdate: '2014-01-31'` it's syncing do not work?

How it should be written:
` startdate: moment(139393998883‌​9).format('YYYY-MM-DD')‌` ?

Comment: To be honest, this component is not terribly well written and most of the comments are in chinese

Comment: gurghet, please show how to correctly write this:  ` startdate: moment(139393998883‌‌​​9).format('YYYY-MM-D‌​D')‌`

Comment: the correct way is in my answer, I was responding to the question "how can I convert (put in variable) in normal format YYYY-MM-DD"

Comment: Oh! Sorry, now I see